# What does "&" mean in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell.
Somebody gave me a symbol and a formula:
m & n = n m
But "&" can't be read by ghci,and we searched the Internet and found no information.
Could anyone tell me what the & means?

Comment: Please post the full code fragment.

Comment: Furthermore this does work in ghci. It simply constructs a function `(&)`.

Comment: I agree with Willem; maybe you forgot a `let`? `let m & n = n m`, then `5 & (+1)` prints 6 as expected.

Comment: Someone gave me a formula `blah m n = n m`. What does `blah` mean? Answer: It means exactly what is defined by the formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(&) operator is defined in Data.Function package. To use it in ghci you have to `import Data.Function`

Then you can use it with the meaning given by the formula you posted.

```
> pi & cos
-1.0
```

Same as:

```
> cos pi
-1.0
```

Answer (score 6):

It's an identifier without any special meaning, so it means whatever you want it to. E.g. in Lens `&` is used as `flip ($)` for convenience, like so:

```
let x = (1,2)
  & _1 +~ 1
  & _2 +~ 2

-- x = (2,4)
```

This also fits your definition of `m & n = n m` (they're equivalent). Any other library can use it for whatever, and if you [use a better search engine](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%26), you'll find numerous ones.

Comment: BTW (and as Hayoo makes clear), this use of `&` is actually defined [in in the `base` package, in `Data.Function`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-). I regularly use this operator even in projects that don't have any lenses at all.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oh, since 7.10.1. I never noticed :)